# Calling a function with feh

Tags: rename, function, feh

I can call an external script with feh, like so:

`feh --action1 ';./renamepic.sh "$PWD/%F"' -F -Z "/Pictures/"`

But how do I call a function inside the same scrip, something under those lines:

```
renamepic(){

  picname=$(basename "$1")              
  picpath=$(dirname "$1")               

  picnewname=$(zenity --entry --text "Please type a new Name" --entry-text "$picname")

  mv "$picpath/$picname" "$picpath/$picnewname"         
}

feh --action1 ';renamepic "$PWD/%F"' -F -Z "/Pictures/"
```

Thanks for help!

Edit:
I just post the correct line for I got it wrong the first time:
feh --action1 "/Slideshow.sh $(PWD)%F" -F -Z "/Pictures/"

Comment: You can't. Or Treat the script as another script, but call it (re-enter) with different arguments so that it calls the function.

Comment: ctrl-alt-delor, many thanks, works neat, didn’t know one could re-enter a script. Cheerio!